# Side-by-side images in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, floats, texmaker, floatrow

I need to put 2 figures side by side in LaTeX where the first figure needs to be given a caption and the second must not be given a caption.
I have tried the following:

```
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{Figure3}}{\caption{PTST based on total duration}\label{case1}}
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{app1}}{\caption{A zoom}\label{zoom}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
```

but I am getting the error do not use float package with float row since I also have `\usepackage{float}` for other images (I need this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `subcaption` package.

Try something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{tikzexample2.png}
\caption{Left figure}
\label{fig:left}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{tikzexample2.png}
\caption{Right figure}
\label{fig:right}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Combined figure}
\label{fig:combined}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It yields the following output.

[image: output example]

Answer (score 4):

May be is not what you wanted (since you have accepted a answer with two subcaptions) but is what your asked ("*the second must not be given a caption*"):

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[h] % Do not use only [h] in real documents.
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{ figure}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the figures are not in same height can the smaller one horizontally centered?

Comment: @alper Sorry, do you mean  one image over the other  as centering A over B with  `{\centering A\\B\par}`? Then, is just replace "A" and "B" by the images  Or really do you mean side by side as in the answers, but the smaller  being *vertically* centered?   Then you can use `[c][x][c]{y}` as minipage arguments, where `x` is the height and `y` the width (obviously with the same `x` in both minipages) or use `adjustbox`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367302/how-to-insert-a-figure-between-two-texts.

Comment: `mean side by side as in the answer, but the smaller being vertically centered?` Yes sir I meant this.

Comment: @alper, Then,  in the MWE of  my answer remove the caption, remove also the options `[t]` and `[b]` (to return to the default `[c]`) and change `example-image-b` `by example-image-16x9 ` (an image with smaller height) . Is this what you expect? But as said, you can also use `adjustbox` and avoid the minipages. [Another  example here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653305/11604)  centering vertically several images.