# How to insert a figure between two texts?

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

I'd like to create something similar to what is give below: text on either side of a vertically centred image:

[image: figure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not remember `adjustbox`, another solutions could be put the image in a table (`tabular`with a singe cell only),  or  a `\parbox,` or a `minipage`. If you want a fine control of the vertical align (i.e, not exactly in the vertical center) may be worth use a `\vbox`:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parskip2em
\begin{document}
Left text% 
\begin{tabular}{c}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}\\
\end{tabular}% 
Right text\par
Left text 
\parbox{2cm}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
Right text\par
Left text \vbox to .83cm{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}}
Right text\par
Left text \vbox to 1.2cm{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}}
Right text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) and it's `valign=c` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

Left text 
\includegraphics[height=50pt,valign=c]{example-image}
Right text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you LaTeX is very interesting and automated by coding. @Werner.