# side by side image that doesn't affect IEEE class? table font and bib indexing got messed up

Tags: bibliographies, subfloats, subcaption, ieeetran, subfig

I am creating document for IEEE conference

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
```

**Goal:** Create side by side image, that doesn't affect other table caption and bibliography indexing

**What I've tried:**

1. [Using `subcaption`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246537/side-by-side-images-in-latex) But it messed up the caption on other table and other figures

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

2. [Using `subfig`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305492/239954) But for some reason the bib index order is messed up

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{flushend}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
    \usepackage[caption=false, font=normalsize, labelfont=sf, textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
\usepackage[caption=false, font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi
```

[image]

**Question:**

1. So what package is best to keep IEEE format when creating side by side image?
2. What I read so far `subfig` is the best option, but if that's the case, what went wrong with my second try?

Comment: You are using several packages I would avoid with IEEE, such as flushend, cite, stfloats and subcaption.  IIRC, IEEE already provides most of the features.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did quick check and yes removing stfloats did fix the problem, but the reason I used stffloats is I have table that spans two-column  that I want to show at the bottom page, and I read that two-column format doesn't have 'bottom'

Comment: According to section X of the IEEEtran manual, bottom floats are strongly discouraged, but are possible using dblfloatfix.  It may conflict with other packages, and the order in which they are loaded may make a difference.