# How to split a page into 6 parts, adding a centered image to each?

Tags: tables, floats, horizontal-alignment, margins, minipage

I have been trying to create a page which is separated into six parts, and then add a figure to each of the sections. Each picture must be centered both horizontally and vertically and must be scalable (within its borders). See figure for what is needed.

[image]

So far I have tried with both `minipage` and tables, but whenever I try to center the pictures it doesn't work. I'm using Overleaf.

This is the closest I have come so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
\usepackage[landscape, paperwidth=15cm, paperheight=30cm, margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\newcommand\Block[2]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\setlength\fboxrule{0.1pt}% delete
\fbox{% delete
\begin{minipage}[c][.5\textheight][t]{0.333333\textwidth}
#1\par #2
\end{minipage}%
  }% delete
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\Block{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/download.jpg}}{}%
\Block{text}{caption}%
\Block{text}{caption}%
\par\nointerlineskip\noindent
\Block{text}{caption}%
\Block{text}{caption}%
\Block{text}{caption}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For finer control, use \makebox and \raisebox.

Comment: I suggest using the *picture environment* package.  In your preamble, you specify a unit size (e.g. 1 inch or 1 cm).  Then, you experiment with the picture package, determinining the max height and width of the page that can be devoted to the picture environment.  Here, temporarily wrapping the picture environment in a frame, will be very helpful.  Then, every diagram goes into a **box** of a specified width, with it's (l, c, or r) justification specified.  Then, you use the picture environment's *put* command to determine the exact (x,y) coordinate of the lower left corner of each box.

Comment: Also, the picture environment allows you to draw grid lines, that can be horizontal, vertical, or any *other* angle.  Further, the picture environment allows you to control the thickness of each grid line.

Comment: The downside of my comments is that if the margins change,  then the maximum height and width of the picture environment will have to be manually adjusted.  Further, if the height or width of the diagrams change, then again, manual adjustments will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

If there are only six <s>figures</s> images, you only need the packages `graphicx` and `adjustvox` for the vertical align:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcommand\img[1]{\includegraphics[valign=c,
width=.25\linewidth,height=.35\textheight,
keepaspectratio]{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \img{example-image}\hfill% 
    \img{example-image-16x9}\hfill%
    \img{example-image-1x1}%
    \par\bigskip\bigskip% change vertical distance as you need
    \img{example-image-1x1}\hfill% 
    \img{example-image-9x16}\hfill%
    \img{example-image-16x9}\par  
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, it was perfect!

Comment: @HenrikGadeKristensen You are welcome, but the way of say thanks in this site is upvote useful answers, and accept the one that  fully solved your problem (accept= click in the left check mark). If lately another answer is even better for you, you can always change your election. Both votes and check marks help to other readers to know at a glance if the question is solved and discover most useful solutions.